# Passing in custom headers with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, python-requests

I am writing to S3 using a pyspark script like so:

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet('s3://[S3_PATH]')
```

With a direct HTTP request, I could pass in custom headers with my write request.  Is it possible to pass in custom headers using PySpark?

Comment: You mean like an `Authorization: Bearer <token>`? If yes, I am also interested in this question!